# Return fetch wrapped by Promise the same as returning fetch?

Tags: javascript, promise

## Background

I started working at a company that doesn't have many patterns and I see the return of `fetch` calls in two ways. One returning just the `fetch` call and another returning a `fetch` call wrapped by `Promise` using `resolve` and `reject`, and this made me get confused.

## Question

Is doing this

```
const returnFetchWrappedByPromise = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return fetch("url")
            .then(resolve(true))
            .catch(reject(false))
    })
}
```

The same as this

```
const returnFetch = () => {
    return fetch("url")
        .then(() => true)
        .catch(() => false)
}
```

?

If not, what is the difference?

If yes, which one should I use?

**Observation:** I used `true` and `false` just to make an example, but in reality, is some result and some error.

Comment: Those should be callbacks: `then(() => true, () => false)`

Comment: Not many patterns, but some antipatterns: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)! And of course: avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Should be easy to test. Run both and see (bearing in mind @Bergi's comments).

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the related posts, this gave me such better understanding of how promises works.

Answer (score -1):

`fetch` inherently returns a promise, so wrapping it in a `new Promise` doesn't add any functionality. The use of `async` also does not add anything in this case and actually presents a case of the [Promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43050114/11417877).

The second function syntax is the preferred way.

Answer (score -1):

The new `Promise` object within the `returnFetchWrappedByPromise` function is not needed. `fetch` already returns a `Promise` object (Screenshot below). You should use the `returnFetch` function. Hope that helps.

[image: Console Screenshot]